# How to get the mouse cursor do a grab on mouse down?

Tags: jquery, css, mouse-cursor

I have made a demo on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uZ377/15/)
**UPDATE** [this version](http://jsfiddle.net/uZ377/21/) works in FF but not chrome..
**UPDATE 2** This [website](http://appear.dk/uk/) seems to have a working solution.

my Javascript is as follows

```
$("#click").live({
  mousedown: function() {
            this.addClass("closed");
        },
  mouseup: function() {
            this.removeClass("closed");
        }
});
```

and the CSS is as follows

```
.closed {
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur), default !important;
}
```

But why doesn't the cursor become a closed hand on mouse down with this jQuery code?
Thank you so much!
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some browsers support this by now: `cursor: -webkit-grabbing; cursor: -moz-grabbing;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**2016 Update:**

Needed to do this in a jQuery slider plugin I'm working on. What I did was define the cursors in CSS, then add/remove them on touch/mouse events with jQuery.

css:

```
.element:hover{
    cursor: move;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: grab;
}
.element.grabbing { 
    cursor: grabbing; 
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".element").on("mousedown touchstart", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('grabbing')
})

$(".element").on("mouseup touchend", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('grabbing')
})
```

Comment: This wouldn't have worked when I had asked the question, I'm glad it works now!

Answer (score 16):

You can get the mouse cursor grab with CSS only:

```
/* Standard cursors */    
.element { cursor: grab; }
.element:active { cursor: grabbing; }

/* Custom cursors */
.element { cursor: url('open-hand.png'), auto; }
.element:active { cursor: url('closed-hand.png'), auto; }
```

Comment: Demo of this solution https://jsfiddle.net/tuq5mpLe/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".surface").mouseup(function(){
        $(".surface").css( "cursor","crosshair");
      }).mousedown(function(){
        $(".surface").css( "cursor","wait");
      });
});
```

Make in css `.surface{cursor:crosshair;}`
If you want to have mouse down/up just change the cursors to hand up/down icon.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

the syntax you're using wasn't introduced until 1.4.3 ([documented here](http://api.jquery.com/live/#multiple-events)), your jsFiddle uses 1.4.2. Your jsFiddle also adds a class to `this`, rather than `$(this)`.

But I'm also not sure about how the cursor CSS reacts to mousedown and mouseup - I have a feeling that may be limiting in some browsers, a bit of fiddling got it working on mouseup, but not mousedown - which seems strange.

Comment: I just find it weird that a simple mouse down or mouse up add class event can be so buggy..